# Suppress console output when loading assemblies via AssemblyResolve

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I have a command line application where I want to load some DLLs at some paths outside my application directory.  I can successfully do this by adding my own ResolveEventHandler.  However, I then get unwanted output in the console like this:

```
Checking for existing AssemblyResolve handler
Removed existing AssemblyResolve handler
```

How can I suppress this output?

Here's my current code:

```
static Assembly LoadPrereq(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.StartsWith("DebugDiag.DotNet"))
        return Assembly.LoadFile("C:\\Program Files\\DebugDiag\\DebugDiag.DotNet.dll");
    return null;
}

...

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(LoadPrereq);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this might help [`Console.SetOut(TextWriter)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setout?view=netframework-4.8)

> Sets the Out property to target the TextWriter object.

For which, you could call the following to disable it

```
Console.SetOut(TextWriter.Null);
```

You might be able save the original with [`Console.Out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.out?view=netframework-4.8) so it can be re-enabled again

> Gets the standard output stream.

<sub>***Note*** : This is untested, and only found via the documentation</sub>

Comment: Yes, a quick test does suggest that will work.  Thank you.